# Yii cache error: Trying to get property of non-object

Tags: php, caching, yii, memcached

I'm using Yii PHP Framework and MemCache for caching and when I open not cached page for the first time I see this error:

**Live error error log off (linux):**

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function getColumnNames() on a non-object in /home/cineshell/cineklik/framework/db/ar/CActiveFinder.php on line 385
```

**Locally with error log (windows):**

```
Trying to get property of non-object
C:\xampp\htdocs\appfolder\framework\yiilite.php(7125)
...
7123     public function getTableSchema()
7124     {
7125         return $this->getMetaData()->tableSchema;
7126     }
```

**config/main:**

```
    'cache'=> array(
        'class'=> 'CMemCache',
          'servers'=>array(
            array('host'=>'localhost', 'port'=>11211, 'weight'=>100),
          ),
    ),
```

**Cache example:**

```
$data = Yii::app()->cache->get( 'casheID'  );
if($data===false)
{
   $data = dataprovider, query... etc
}
echo $data;
```

So, what's error here ?, and could be something in server settings ?

someone told me use `if isset` but I'm not understand !

Comment: What are you caching?

Comment: @Aktiiv dataprovider, query..

Answer (score 1):

For CActiveDataProvider, please follow this guide.
http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/233/using-cache-in-cactivedataprovider/

For alternative, you can use fragment cache the gridview or the partial view depending the needs. I've also struggeled with it and I found that query cache was the only working solution.

Comment: thanks, but I can use seconds for cache dependency because I'm not have update_time ?

Comment: Yes. 
$posts = Post::model()->cache(1000, $dependency)->findAll();

Here 1000 is the seconds when cache invalidates.
Take a look at great documentation:
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/caching.data#using-query-caching-with-activerecord